# Calculating savings based on p50 and p90 usage

Tags: statistics

Let's say I get billed for using a service across multiple people, where `Rate` is constant:

```
IndividualCost1 = Rate * UsageMinutes
IndividualCost2 = Rate * UsageMinutes
...
IndividualCostX = Rate * UsageMinutes

TotalCost = IndividualCost1 + IndividualCost2 + ... + IndividualCostX
```

Let's say last year's `TotalCost` was $100, and I expect cost this year to go down significantly as the service has become more efficient - individuals may be able to achieve the same goal without using the service as much (*maybe* less `UsageMinutes` per individual).

If I know last year's cost of $100 along with both the old AND new p50/p90 (any statistical point e.g. p10, p25, etc) for all `UsageMinutes` (e.g. p50 would be `50% of all individual usage minutes was under Z`), would I be able to get an approximation of the new cost this year? e.g. last year's p50 `UsageMinutes = 10 minutes` and this year's p50 `UsageMinutes = 8 minutes`.

Not sure if this makes sense but this is the best way I could explain it. I've been thinking about this for a while but I can't wrap my head around it. Would it only be a p50 estimated cost? p90 estimated cost? Can I get an overall cost reduction?

For example, given:

```
Last year:

TotalCost = 100
Individual UsageMinutes p50 = 10 minutes
```

and

```
This year:

TotalCost = ?
Individual UsageMinutes p50 = 8 minutes
```

is it as simple as `This year's TotalCost = 100 * 8/10 = 80`? I don't know much about statistics, but I was thinking p50 would be the closest to "expected/average" (even though it's median) savings..